# send http requests, keep session alive: C/C++ with cURL(axus camera)

Tags: c++, http, curl, request, axis

Ive a problem and i cant figure at all how i can manage to solve the following problem:
I would like to send multiple http request to an axis camera. 
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http:/root:309@IPADDRESS");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
//    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    res=curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http:/IPADDRESS/axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi?move=left");
    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

All i want to do in this example, is to keep my session alive after being logged to the IPaddress, and then send the order "move=left" to this very ip address.
When i execute this program, i got those messages:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT"> 
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=/view/index.shtml">
Your browser has JavaScript turned off.<br>For the user interface to work effectively, you must enable JavaScript in your browser and reload/refresh this page.
  </noscript>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>401 Unauthorized</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>401 Unauthorized</H1>
Your client does not have permission to get URL /axis-cgi/com/ptz.cgi from this server.
</BODY></HTML>
```

I assume that i wasnt even logged to the ipaddress...

I never really used this kind of method before... Can you help me with this?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: It looks like you have to use the `curl_multi_*` functions, and enable `CURLMOPT_PIPELINING`. You have to register your `CURL *` with a `CURLM *`. I found an example [here](http://darcs.net/release/src/hscurl.c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add these two options:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
```

From documentation:

> **CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE**
>
> Pass a pointer to a zero terminated string as parameter. It should
>   contain the name of your file holding cookie data to read. The cookie
>   data may be in Netscape / Mozilla cookie data format or just regular
>   HTTP-style headers dumped to a file.
>
> Given an empty or non-existing file or by passing the empty string
>   (""), this option will enable cookies for this curl handle, making it
>   understand and parse received cookies and then use matching cookies in
>   future requests.
>
> If you use this option multiple times, you just add more files to
>   read. Subsequent files will add more cookies.
>
> **CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR**
>
> Pass a file name as char *, zero terminated. This will make libcurl
>   write all internally known cookies to the specified file when
>   curl_easy_cleanup(3) is called. If no cookies are known, no file will
>   be created. Specify "-" to instead have the cookies written to stdout.
>   Using this option also enables cookies for this session, so if you for
>   example follow a location it will make matching cookies get sent
>   accordingly.
>
> If the cookie jar file can't be created or written to (when the
>   curl_easy_cleanup(3) is called), libcurl will not and cannot report an
>   error for this. Using CURLOPT_VERBOSE or CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION will
>   get a warning to display, but that is the only visible feedback you
>   get about this possibly lethal situation

Read more at: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html